# what defines a recursive function?

Tags: c++, c, recursion

Beyond the simple question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13098975/2963099)
And based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826746/trying-to-generate-9-digit-numbers-with-each-unique-digits/32059779#comment51972274_31885811) comment

The question is at what point does a solution stop being considered recursive, even if the base algorithm implemented is recursive?

For completeness, the following functions are used by all cases:

```
int counter=0;
int reps=0;

void show(int x)
{
#ifdef OUTPUT
    printf("==============>>> %d <<<\n", x);
#endif
    counter+=x;
    ++reps;
}

int bit_val(unsigned int v)
{
  static const int MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition2[32] =
  {
    0, 1, 28, 2, 29, 14, 24, 3, 30, 22, 20, 15, 25, 17, 4, 8,
    31, 27, 13, 23, 21, 19, 16, 7, 26, 12, 18, 6, 11, 5, 10, 9
  };
  return MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition2[(unsigned int)(v * 0x077CB531U) >> 27];
}
```

**CASE 1: Clear recursion**

```
void uniq_digitsR(int places, int prefix, int used) {
  if (places==1) {
    show(prefix*10+bit_val(~used));
    return;
  }
  int base=prefix*10;
  unsigned int unused=~used;
  while(unused) {
    unsigned int diff=unused & (unused-1);
    unsigned int bit=unused-diff;
    unused=diff;
    uniq_digitsR(places-1, base+bit_val(bit), used|bit);
  }
}

int uniq_digits9() {
  unsigned int used=~((1<<10)-1); // set all bits except 0-9
  used |= 1;                      // unset 0
  uniq_digitsR(9, 0, used);
  return 0;
}
```

**CASE 2:  Hardcoded Unrolling**

Note that at no time does a function call itself or any direct or indirect caller

```
void uniq_digits1(int prefix, unsigned int used) {
  show(prefix*10+bit_val(~used));
}

void uniq_digits2(int prefix, unsigned int used) {
  int base=prefix*10;
  unsigned int unused=~used;
  while (unused) {
    unsigned int diff=unused & (unused-1);
    unsigned int bit=unused-diff;
    unused=diff;
    uniq_digits1(base+bit_val(bit), used|bit);
  }
}

void uniq_digits3(int prefix, unsigned int used) {
  int base=prefix*10;
  unsigned int unused=~used;
  while (unused) {
    unsigned int diff=unused & (unused-1);
    unsigned int bit=unused-diff;
    unused=diff;
    uniq_digits2(base+bit_val(bit), used|bit);
  }
}

void uniq_digits4(int prefix, unsigned int used) {
  int base=prefix*10;
  unsigned int unused=~used;
  while (unused) {
    unsigned int diff=unused & (unused-1);
    unsigned int bit=unused-diff;
    unused=diff;
    uniq_digits3(base+bit_val(bit), used|bit);
  }
}

void uniq_digits5(int prefix, unsigned int used) {
  int base=prefix*10;
  unsigned int unused=~used;
  while (unused) {
    unsigned int diff=unused & (unused-1);
    unsigned int bit=unused-diff;
    unused=diff;
    uniq_digits4(base+bit_val(bit), used|bit);
  }
}

void uniq_digits6(int prefix, unsigned int used) {
  int base=prefix*10;
  unsigned int unused=~used;
  while (unused) {
    unsigned int diff=unused & (unused-1);
    unsigned int bit=unused-diff;
    unused=diff;
    uniq_digits5(base+bit_val(bit), used|bit);
  }
}

void uniq_digits7(int prefix, unsigned int used) {
  int base=prefix*10;
  unsigned int unused=~used;
  while (unused) {
    unsigned int diff=unused & (unused-1);
    unsigned int bit=unused-diff;
    unused=diff;
    uniq_digits6(base+bit_val(bit), used|bit);
  }
}

void uniq_digits8(int prefix, unsigned int used) {
  int base=prefix*10;
  unsigned int unused=~used;
  while (unused) {
    unsigned int diff=unused & (unused-1);
    unsigned int bit=unused-diff;
    unused=diff;
    uniq_digits7(base+bit_val(bit), used|bit);
  }
}

void uniq_digits9() {
  unsigned int used=~((1<<10)-1); // set all bits except 0-9
  used |= 1;                      // unset 0
  for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    unsigned int bit=1<<i;
    uniq_digits8(i,used|bit);
  }
}
```

**CASE 3: Iterative Version**

Note that no functions are called (aside from obviously show) but it is the same algorithm

```
void uniq_digits(const int array[], const int length) {
  unsigned int unused[length-1];                    // unused prior
  unsigned int combos[length-1];                    // digits untried
  int digit[length];                                // printable digit
  int mult[length];                                 // faster calcs
  mult[length-1]=1;                                 // start at 1
  for (int i = length-2; i >= 0; --i)
     mult[i]=mult[i+1]*10;                          // store multiplier
  unused[0]=combos[0]=((1<<(length))-1);            // set all bits 0-length
  int depth=0;                                      // start at top
  digit[0]=0;                                       // start at 0
  while(1) {
    if (combos[depth]) {                            // if bits left
      unsigned int avail=combos[depth];             // save old
      combos[depth]=avail & (avail-1);              // remove lowest bit
      unsigned int bit=avail-combos[depth];         // get lowest bit
      digit[depth+1]=digit[depth]+mult[depth]*array[bit_val(bit)]; // get associated digit
      unsigned int rest=unused[depth]&(~bit);       // all remaining
      depth++;                                      // go to next digit
      if (depth!=length-1) {                        // not at bottom
        unused[depth]=combos[depth]=rest;           // try remaining
      } else {
        show(digit[depth]+array[bit_val(rest)]);    // print it
        depth--;                                    // stay on same level
      }
    } else {
      depth--;                                      // go back up a level
      if (depth < 0)
        break;                                      // all done
    }
  }
}
```

So, is just `CASE 1` recursive?  Or do we also include `CASE 2` or even `CASE 3`?

Comment: While you don't understand recursion read this sentence from the beginning.

Comment: Is this a Stackreview question? What problem are you having with the code, or is this a philosophical enquiry?

Comment: Isn't the [formal recursion definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#Formal_definitions) clearly answer the question?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: That's more like a `while` loop...

Comment: that question is better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @mort or a `do` loop?

Comment: @mort no. It's a recursive definition of recursion. Syntax is not semantics.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32104129/what-defines-a-recursive-function

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a difference between a *recursive definition* of a function, and its *recursive implementation* (or algorithm).

A function may be mathematically defined in a recursive manner, but an algorithm (i.e. implementation) which calculates this function may well be non-recursive, and vice versa.

Note that there may be different mathematical definitions and different algorithms for the same function.

---

In the examples you've provided, it's totally obvious that *CASE 1-implementation* is recursive, while *CASE 2-* and *CASE 3-implementations* are not recursive, regardless if the mathematical definition of the function was recursive or not.

---

*P.S. to keep it in the question's scope, I intentionally didn't touch direct/indirect recursion, nor some pure functional languages which express iterations through recursion only.*

Comment: Great answer. The distinction between the mathematical definition and the implementation is often overlooked.

Comment: And in fact some algorithms are implemented in a way that's _both_ recursive and iterative. Sorting, for instance, is typically defined recursively down to 1 element which by definition is always sorted. Real implementations recurse down to 8 elements or so, and then switch to an iterative sort. This is significantly faster in practice as a lot of time in sorting is spent on sorting all those small subsets.

Answer (score 2):

A solution stops being recursive when at no time, for any inputs, does there appear more than one instance of any function in the activation chain: no function is re-entered.

Is the "unrolled recursion" recursion or not? That depends whether we are talking about the concept on which the unrolled solution is based on, or its implementation.

Clearly, the implementation isn't recursive.

Clearly, the unrolled copies of the function are a mechanical repetition based on a recursive implementation, and the solution still expresses some aspects of that solution; when you look at the code, it is obvious how it can be rolled back into a recursive implementation. We can also validate that solution against the recursive description of the algorithm; that is to say, using a description of the recursive algorithm as our guide, we can easily convince ourselves whether the unrolled implementation is right or wrong.

So clearly, the unrolled code is exactly that: an unrolled implementation of the recursive solution. We cannot deny the connection to the recursive specification, yet we have to acknowledge that recursion isn't taking place.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand a bit on the answer @AlexShesterov gave. explicit recursion is generally expensive, and depending on the use case it risks overflowing the stack, which is why in practice it's commonly avoided through similar transformations to yours.

Consider a *tail-recursive* function.  A *tail-recursive* function, like it sounds, is a function that does not keep any state in the function call (the recursive call is at the end).  Compilers will normally implement these as iterative code since it's a trivial transformation.

Recursion is a very succinct way to describe a function though, which is why a lot are described using it (i.e. Fibonacci numbers).  However, in practice it is generally better to reformulate them iteratively.

With Fibonacci numbers you have...

```
F(0) = 0
F(1) = 1
F(N) = F(N-1) + F(N-2)
```

So, normally in C++ it can be implemented recursively with...

```
size_t fib(size_t n) {

  if (n == 0)
    return 0;

  if (n == 1)
    return 1;

   return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
```

Although, it's inefficient (recomputing values, storing data on call stack, etc...).  One optimization would *memoizing* the function calls.  However, the actual value can be constructed from the bottom up, so it's better to simply re-formulate it iteratively.

```
size_t fib(size_t n) {

  size_t p = 0, c = 1;

  if (n == 0)
    return 0;

   while (n--) {

     size_t t = c;

     c = p + c;
     p = t;
   }

  return c;
}
```

For fun, here's the same thing in haskell...

```
fib n = fibs !! n
  where fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

Answer (score 1):

The word recursion is used in different contexts. You have the simple definition of a recursive function where a function either calls itself directly of indirectly, but in computer science you also say something about a processes.

An iterative process is basically a primitive recursive function. It is all functions that can be defined by iteration or tail recursion. Examples:

```c
int test (int x)
{
  return x + 1;
}

int factorial(int x)
{
   int a = 1;
   while( x > 1 ) {
       a *= x;
   }
   return a;
}

int factorial_aux(int x, int a)
{
   return x == 0 ? a : factorial_aux(x-1, a*x);
}
```

A recursive process is an process which always would need some kind of data structure to keep data while it's processing in order to track back. An example of that might be tree traversal:

```c
Node* search(Node* tree, int needle) {
  if( tree == NULL  || tree->value == needle )
    return tree;
  else
    return search(tree->left, needle) || search(tree->right, needle);
}

Node* search(Node* tree, int needle) {
  Stack<Node *> stack;
  if( tree )
    stack.push(tree);

  while ( stack.empty() == false ) {
      Node* n = stack.pop();
      if( n->value == needle )
          return n;

      if( tree->right != NULL )
         stack.push(tree->right);
      if( tree->left != NULL )
         stack.push(tree->left);
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Both of the above are recursive processes. The fact that one use a recursive function and the other an iterative function using a loop does not change the fact that the system stack or explicit stack will grow as the process visits nodes further from the root.

The CPUs usually doesn't support most of these things so a compiler needs to do a lot of "emulating" by using primitive instructions and pushing and cleaning up stack for argument passing. Thus under the hood a recursive function is often an iterative procedure with a growing stack.

So to answer your question:

- **For a process:**  When the space used is constant
- **For a function:** When there is no possibility for a direct or indirect self call